# Rails: Search Array of Hashes Using Scope

Tags: arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, search, hash

I have a reservation system and I want to store the user_id of people who buy the tickets of an event, with the number of tickets bought in an array of hashes. So, it would be like:

`[{"id" => "1", "no" => "3"}, {"id" => "4", "no" => "2"}]`

It means that user_id 1 reserved 3 seats in this event ...

The database I'm using is PostgreSQL and I defined this field as `text, array: true` with the name of `reservations` to use the power of array in psql.

The problem is to search this field to show each user his reservations and corresponding quantity. I need to define a scope in the Event model and call it from the User controller. As a result, each user can see his reservations in his dashboard. I tried many many ways but still have problem. Any idea and help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating separated table and store there `user_id` and `seats_count`. You can name it `UserReservation`. You can then update `User` model and have

```
class User
  has_many :user_reservations
end
```

so you can easily fetch all user reservations by calling `current_user.user_reservations.joins(:event)`

Comment: Thanks, It's the alternative solution but I wanted to know if it's possible to do it using arrays and hashes (without adding another table).